# Eclipse local Find Replace macro with predefined terms?

Tags: eclipse, macros, replace

How would one automate a commonly used search replace action in Eclipse?

My current workflow is as follows:

- Double click on function bracket selecting function
- Ctrl-F opening Find / Replace dialog
- Type "foo." in Find box (alternatively can use pulldown menu but that is slower)
- Type "bar->" in Replace box
- Press Replace All button

Ideal macro would do all of the above bound to a single command.

From my search, it doesn't look possible in plain vanilla Eclipse, but perhaps there is a plugin which can do this?

Using: Eclipse Helios for C/C++ developers

Comment: If you have to do this blindly on a bunch of source files, I would just use an external tool, like winGrep if you are on Windows, or the useful Unix tools (find+sed, probably) otherwise.

Comment: PhilHO - thats the thing, I can't use it blindly. :)

Comment: OK, I had to be sure this option wasn't overlooked (sometime the obvious is too obvious, particularly when you have a powerful tool in the hands...). Another option is to use an external automation tool like AutoHotkey or AutoIt. But both are for Windows, and doesn't work well with Java dialogs... Haven't tried on Eclipse. Might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the [Practical Macro](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/) plugin.

There is even an [example](http://sourceforge.net/projects/practicalmacro/forums/forum/878739/topic/3389467) on the forums showing a Find/Replace macro definition.

Comment: Excellent! I really miss such macro stuff in Eclipse. There was a monkey script or something, but it has been abandoned.